# Может ли boost::signals2 подписывать методы экземпляров класса?

Tags: c++, boost

Я разбираюсь с boost::singals2 и в своих тестах, пробую осуществить подписку на метод экземпляра класса:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void method(int n)
    {
        std::cout << "MyClass::method " << n << std::endl;
    }
    void method2(int n)
    {
        std::cout << "MyClass::method2 " << n << std::endl;
    }
};


boost::signals2::signal<void(int n)> TestSignal;

MyClass myClass;

TestSignal.connect(myClass.method);
```

Однако программка не компилируется, не пойму как подписаться на метод конкретного экземпляра класса, возможно ли подобное ? Можно конечно обернуть метод класса в std::function и функтор, однако хотелось бы иметь возможность подписать именно метод класса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TestSignal.connect(boost::bind(&MyClass::method, &myClass, _1));
```

Comment: Нужно ли подключать какие либо заголовочные файлы ? я попробовал, не получилось - вышла ошибка
Error C2440  'return': cannot convert from 'R' to 'R (__cdecl &)' На сколько я понял, он выдает ее из за того что не все параметры зафиксированы.

Comment: Получилось. Благодарю за помощь.
TestSignal.connect(boost::bind(&MyClass::method,&myClass,_1));